# Cin With Spaces and ","

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am trying to figure out how to take a `string` that a user enters with space as a single `string`. Moreover, after that, the user will include other `strings` separated by commas.

For example, `foo,Hello World,foofoo` where `foo` is one `string` followed by `Hello World` and `foofoo`.

What I have right now, it would split `Hello World` into two `strings` instead of combining them into one.

```
int main()
{
    string stringOne, stringTwo, stringThree;
    cout << "Enter a string with commas and a space";
    cin >> stringOne;  //User would enter in, for this example foo,Hello World,foofoo

    istringstream str(stringOne);

    getline(str, stringOne, ',');       
    getline(str, stringTwo, ',');
    getline(str, stringThree);

    cout << stringOne; //foo
    cout << endl;
    cout << stringTwo; //Hello World <---should be like this, but I am only getting Hello here
    cout << endl;
    cout << stringThree; //foofoo
    cout << endl;
}
```

How do I get `Hello World` into `stringTwo` as a single string instead of two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Do you have a question for us?

Comment: @RSahu Sorry, my question is how do I get `Hello World` into `stringTwo` as a single string instead of two.

Comment: Comma separated data is handled in [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: @Mitchel0022 I've checked that post out, and the OP was asking about how to split the `string`. I want to combine it into one `string`

Comment: Please take the time to convert your posed code to a [mcve] and post that. I can see where the problems are but it will make more sense to respond with an answer after I see a MCVE.

Comment: @RSahu I've made some edits to my original post.

Comment: Use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>` to read the user's input: `getline(cin, stringOne);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is:

```
foo,Hello World,foofoo
```

Your first line that reads input from `std::cin` is:

```
cin >> stringOne;
```

That line reads everything until it finds the first whitespace character to `stringOne`. After that line, the value of `strinOne` will be `"foo,Hello"`.

In the lines

```
getline(str, stringOne, ',');       
getline(str, stringTwo, ',');
```

`"foo"` is assigned to `stringOne` and `"Hello"` is assigned to `stringTwo`.

In the line

```
getline(str, stringThree);
```

nothing is assigned to `stringThree` since there is nothing else left in the `str` object.

You can fix the problem by changing the first line that reads from `std::cin` so that the entire line is assigned to `stringOne`, not the contents up to the first whitespace character.

```
getline(cin, stringOne);

istringstream str(stringOne);

getline(str, stringOne, ',');       
getline(str, stringTwo, ',');
getline(str, stringThree);
```

Comment: Ah..ok I see now. Thank you for the help!.